# How to call async function inside request-promise object?

Tags: node.js, async-await, http-headers, request-promise

I have a function given below:

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var gzipEncoding=require('./gzipClass');
(async()=>{
    request({headers:{"Accept-Encoding": "gzip"},uri:"https://www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/", method: 'HEAD'}, function (err, res, body){
    console.log(res.headers['content-encoding']);
    const result= await  gzipEncoding.checkForGzipEncoding(res.headers)
    console.log(result)
});
})()
```

But I an getting this error

```
 const result= await  gzipEncoding.checkForGzipEncoding(res.headers)
                  ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

T think it because I am calling an async function inside the request. How can a call an async function inside the request? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `async` to the callback when calling `request`.

```
    request({
        headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip" }, uri: "https://www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/", method: "HEAD" }, 
        async function (err, res, body) {
            console.log(res.headers["content-encoding"]);
            const result = await gzipEncoding.checkForGzipEncoding(res.headers)
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```